# Conditionnal relay in postfix

Tags: linux, email, postfix

I use postfix to send direct email. But, I use a relay to send email for specific senders. So I use "sender_dependent_relayhost_maps" :

`/etc/postfix/main.cf` :

```
relayhost =
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_relay
```

`/etc/postfix/sender_relay` :

```
address@domain.com smtp.relay.com
```

So when I send an email with sender email "address@domain.com", postfix will use the relay.

But... I don't want to use the relay host for some recipient. ;)

I think I must use "transport_map" to catch the email before it pass through "sender_dependent_relayhost_maps" but I don't know how to do it...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution... :)

So in the `main.cf` I add, **before** "sender_dependent_relayhost_maps" :

```
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

And, in "transport" file, I just add :

```
domain.com smtp:
```

(nothing else after "smtp:" which significate that the smtp server will send directly the email)

Thanks anyway. ;)