# Different postfix relayhost based on system user?

Tags: linux, email, postfix

How do I configure Postfix to send email through a different relayhost based the system user?

The current setup has relayhost= set so all mail goes through that smtp server but I would like Postfix to send directly based on system user.

I'm open to other options that would allow a script to in some way have Postfix override the relayhost.

transport_maps based on recipient domain unfortunately won't work in this case as it's not the recipient domain that determines what relayhost is chosen.

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps this is what you are looking for? http://serverfault.com/questions/400549/conditionnal-relay-in-postfix

Comment: Thanks I saw similar solutions but I couldn't use that as it's based on recipient domain.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by system user? The sender will be user@domain in that case or for a single system user you could have different senders? Could different system users share a sender?

Answer (score 1):

I took a hint from the post [Use different relay in postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/386757/use-different-relay-in-postfix) and used `header_checks` to assign the proper transport for emails that I had inserted an X-Foo header into:

```
# cat /etc/postfix/main.cf
...
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

# cat /etc/postfix/header_checks
...
/^X-Foo: 1/ FILTER relay:otherhost.com:25
```

`relayhost` was commented out (default) in `/etc/postfix/main.cf` but it could've been anything and you'd use the `header_checks` to override it