# Conditional use of relay(smarthost) for recipient domains matched by header_checks in postfix

Tags: email, postfix, smarthost

On a postfix mailserver, which is configured to generally send mail directly (internet-site), I want to implement a conditional header check for some receipient domains (in this example to keep it simple just with gmail.com), to let postfix use a smarthost. 
But, instead of authenticating with the smarthost smtp.google.com, it just keeps sending the mails addressed To: *@gmail* directly (if I set a wrong password on purpose, it does not complain about).

I created the following files in /etc/postfix/:

relay_passwd:

```
smtp.google.com mygmailaccount@gmail.com:mypassword
```

header_checks:

```
^To: <*@gmail*>/ FILTER relay:smtp.gmail.com:25
```

and referenced them in main.cf with additional options:

```
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relay_passwd
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

now I postmapped the files (and since, restarted postfix too multiple times):

```
# postmap relay_passwd
# postmap header_checks
```

and it throws a warning:

```
postmap: warning: header_checks, line 1: record is in "key: value" format; is this an alias file?
```

But I guess that's not the problem, is it? Anyway, I must be doing something wrong.

I found the following threads but they're not quite what I want:

[Use different relay in postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/386757/use-different-relay-in-postfix)

[Conditionnal relay in postfix](https://serverfault.com/questions/400549/conditionnal-relay-in-postfix)

[Different postfix relayhost based on system user?](https://serverfault.com/questions/646786/different-postfix-relayhost-based-on-system-user?lq=1)

Is the order in main.cf relevant? Is the regexp in header_checks ok?

Comment: Looking at http://www.postfix.org/header_checks.5.html the format of the `header_checks` file should be `/pattern/flag action`. Your line is missing the starting `/`. Also, the regular expression is incorrect - `*` means "0 or more occurrences of the preceding character/block". The line should most probably be `/^To: .*<.*@gmail.*>/ FILTER relay:smtp.gmail.com:25` - note the `.*` before the e-mail address to match names. There are still more problems with the regex (like that it will match address foo@gmailwhatever.tld) but this should be a decent start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it, your relay configuration looks fine.

```
/^To: (.*?)@gmail.com$/ FILTER smtp:smtp.gmail.com
```

Also, you don't need to postmap regexp files.

Source: [Marcelog](http://marcelog.github.io/articles/configure_postfix_forward_email_regex_subject_transport_relay.html)